# Which version of XAMPP is compatible for php 5.4.45 and where can I find it?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My hosting server have `php 5.4.45` installed along with `mysql 5.6.28-76.1` `cpanel 58.0 (build 47)`

I've got so many errors because I was using latest XAMPP with PHP 7.1 on my computer. I want to be in sync with my server.

Please provide me details where can I find the compatible version of XAMPP which resolves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of XAMPP to be based on PHP 5.4 [appears to have been the XAMPP 1.8.2-x series](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/news-article-218371.html), culminating in version 1.8.2-6.

[But it also seems that 1.8.2 series used MySQL 5.5 not 5.6](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20140218.html). The first version of XAMPP to do that seems to have been 1.8.3-x, with the final version of that series being 1.8.3-5.

Both may be available on sites that specialize in older versions of software. However, your best choice may currently be [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/).

Just as a small note - if neither of these satisfy your needs, you can do a little bit of legwork and set all three up fairly easily without the need of XAMPP.